# Log into website and use pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, urllib

I have a unique scenario I am running into and looking for a solution. There is a table I would like to scrape using pandas but the issue is it requires me to log into the website. Because I have a monthly subscription I am then able to view the entire table otherwise it returns the first twenty rows and some are `NaN`. New to pandas and love how easy a script is for tables. This is the logged in view. All data available. I have only used selenium for logging in and that's where the idea came from.  [image]

[Here is the link](https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/game_finder.cgi?request=1&match=basic&series=any&series_game=any&min_year_game=2018&max_year_game=2018&WL=any&team_id=ANY&opp_id=ANY&game_length=any&bats=any&throws=any&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&HV=any&GS=anyGS&GF=anyGF&is_birthday=either&temperature_min=0&temperature_max=120&wind_speed_min=0&wind_speed_max=90&as=result_batter&class=player&offset=0&type=b&c1gtlt=gt&c2gtlt=gt&c3gtlt=gt&c4gtlt=gt&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1.0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&orderby=HR&number_matched=1)

```
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import urllib


dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/game_finder.cgi?request=1&'
                   'match=basic&series=any&series_game=any&min_year_game=2018&max_year_game=2018'
                   '&WL=any&team_id=ANY&opp_id=ANY&game_length=any&bats=any&throws=any&pos_1=1&pos_2=1'
                   '&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1'
                   '&exactness=any&HV=any&GS=anyGS&GF=anyGF&is_birthday=either&temperature_min=0&temperature_max'
                   '=120&wind_speed_min=0&wind_speed_max=90&as=result_batter&class=player&offset=0&type=b&c1gtlt'
                   '=gt&c2gtlt=gt&c3gtlt=gt&c4gtlt=gt&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1.0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&orderby=HR&number_matched=1')

    for df in dfs:
        pprint(dfs)


        df.to_csv('ALL_Ref_AtBats.csv', mode='w')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium` for web automation since you need to automate logging.

The other solution would be to use requests and send cookies while issuing a GET method for the URL.

Comment: Using selenium, once im at the landing page after logging in how would i store the html as a df

Comment: Use selenium to save the page to local disk. Then use pd.read_html to read local html file.

Comment: Does it matter if the table is larger than one page?

Comment: It only matters if the data you are looking for is loaded dynamically with page scroll. Otherwise, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, Ill have to look up the save with selenium. Not familiar with that.